# Monitor for sub classes

Tags: ruby, concurrency

I need a class mutex for all subclasses of a specific base class. Since the `MonitorMixin` provides an easy interface via `synchronize` I tried to use the mixin.

But I couldn't find a solution for extending the base class.

```
require 'monitor'

class Base
  def self.some
    synchronize { puts 'some' }
  end
end
Base.extend(MonitorMixin)

class A < Base; end
class B < Base; end

A.some
# /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:215:in `mon_enter': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
#         from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:240:in `synchronize'
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: When you say "class mutex for all subclasses", do you mean that each subclass should have its own mutex on that method, or that all subclasses should share a mutex with the parent class?

Comment: @Max Every subclass should have its own mutex. BTW: The base class is `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this with monitor, but it's pretty easy if you don't mind using the inherited hook:

```
class Base
  def self.some
    @mutex.synchronize { puts 'some' }
  end

  # each subclass gets its own mutex
  def self.inherited subclass
    subclass.instance_variable_set :@mutex, Mutex.new
  end
end
```

Comment: Within the hook you can call `subclass.extend(MonitorMixin)` which works with my snippet above. But I'm not sure it works with `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Comment: @sschmeck, why do you think it wouldn't work with `ActiveRecord::Base`?

Comment: @ndn What if the `inherited()` is already defined for `ActiveRecord::Base`? The monkey-patching seems dangerous.

Comment: @sschmeck, then you can just invoke `super` at the end of this definition of `inherited`. Also that is what `ApplicationRecord` is for (so you don't have to monkey patch `ActiveRecord::Base`).

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following solution using the `inherited()` hook.

```
module SubclassMonitor
  def inherited(subclass)
    super
    subclass.extend(MonitorMixin)
  end
end

Base.extend(SubclassMonitor)
```